# Github plugin triggering to push event only for changes in specific branches

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, github

I am using Jenkins2 and GitHub plugin for triggering **Push** events.

I have the next service (Jenkins Github): http://myjenkinsmaster/github-webhook/

I also have 3 branches: `dev`, `stage`, `master` which need to be built.

But I require only the branch with changes to be built.

For example if changes were pushed to `dev`, only `dev` branch will be built, and others ignored.

However, Jenkins builds all 3 branches which I specified in branch field in job config.

How can I achieve a Jenkins build that builds only the branch where changes were pushed?

Comment: Do you use pipelines for jenkins jobs?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I have resolved it with the help of "strategy of choosing what to build" with "Default behavior" for each branch.

Comment: Please elaborate your answer. Your answer will help others as well, so adding more explanation and a screenshot always helps :)